# How to access an element of a multidimensional array via a list of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, tensor, indices

I would like to access a specific element of a multidimensional array (i.e. a tensor) via a defined list of indices. Let's say I have an array `P` in 4 dimension, and a list of indices `ind` defined as:

```
 ind = [0,4,1,3]
```

which characterized one of its elements. I would like to assign "something" to the element `P[0,4,1,3]`. However, when I do:

```
 P[ind] = "something"
```

Python understands `P[[0,4,1,3]]` instead of `P[0,4,1,3]`.

So, how could I access the element `P[0,4,1,3]` via `ind`?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**:

To set a value in an N-dimensional list by a given list of indices the following setter function can be used:

```
def set_val(ndim, ind, val):
    arr = ndim
    for i in ind[:-1]:
        arr = arr[i]
    arr[ind[-1]] = val

# usage:
P = [[[42]]]
set_val(P, [0, 0, 0,], 9001)
```

**Original answer**:

To set elements corresponding to given indices of a plain Python list you need to run a loop, something like this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
ind = [0, 4, 1, 3]
val = 42
for i in ind:
    arr[i] = val
```

Plain Python does not provide vector operations on lists. You might be confusing Python with Pandas.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you for your answer. But "ind" corresponds actually to only one element of a multidimensional array (I edited my question; my apologies, I think it was not clear enough).

Comment: So, what's the actual type of the _multidimentional array_? It might actually support some specific access methods. But if we need to access a leaf element of a plain 4d list a recursive function can be used.

Comment: It is a numpy.ndarray

Comment: I'm not an expert in numpy, but you can try to set a value like this `P[np.array([0,4,1,3])] = 'something'`.

Comment: Your updated answer with the definition of set_val works well.
Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Even though `set_val` might work, it's not optimal to use functions like this with numpy data structures. Numpy is a highly optimized data processing library and it's always better to use native numpy capabilities for vectorized operations than trying to mimic the desired behavior on the Python user space.