# Access a multidimensional arrays by a set of indices

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I am dealing with a huge multidimensional Python list, and I want to access it by a set of indices. For example, give `data` (list of lists of lists of ...) and list `lst` of arbitrary size. And I need to access `data[lst[0]][lst[1]][lst[2]][...`

Could you please tell me, is there any way to do this without tons of copying (like this:)

```
data_tmp = data
for elem in lst:
    data_tmp = data_tmp[elem]
```

There is this one: [How to access an element of a multidimensional array via a list of indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930948/how-to-access-an-element-of-a-multidimensional-array-via-a-list-of-indices)

But it actually uses tons of copying.

Comment: there are zero copies made in your code, nor is there any copying in the code you linked to. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay, got it. But how slow is `data_tmp = data_tmp[elem]` for large enough list? Does it run in O(1) time?

Comment: I don't think you get it. There are no copies being made.

Comment: also, `data[elem]` doesn't make sense, almost certainly, that is not what you mean.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga please, can you explain then, what does `data_tmp = data_tmp[elem]` do, if not copying?

Comment: `data_tmp[elem]` accesses an object in the list at index `elem`  and assigns it to the variable `data_tmp`. No copies would be made. Not sure why you would expect any copies to be made.  Similarly, `data_tmp = data` does nothing useful: it assigns the object that is being referenced by the variable `data` to another variable, `data_tmp`, no copies are made. You should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html